# Is it possible to filter an igx actionstrip menu based on a field value from a grid row?

Tags: angular, igx-grid

I have a grid with records that all contain a status.  On the grid I have an actionstrip with two current entries, Submit and Delete:

```
<igx-action-strip #actionstrip [context]="batchListGrid.data">
              <ng-container>
                <div *igxActionStripMenuItem class="menu-button" (click)="setCurrentBatch(actionstrip.context, 'submit')" igxRipple>
                  <igx-icon>outbox</igx-icon>
                  <span>Submit</span>
                </div>
                <div *igxActionStripMenuItem class="menu-button" (click)="setCurrentBatch(actionstrip.context, 'delete')" igxRipple>
                  <igx-icon>delete</igx-icon>
                  <span>Delete</span>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </igx-action-strip>
```

What I would like to do is only display the menu items that meet a certain status.  *ngIf is not allowed because only one structural directive is allowed.  I tried using a standard drop down, but the record field isn't available in the action strip -- hopefully i am missing something simple.  Anyone can help me with what I hope is a "duh" moment?